# Set a default hidden value with an id in a ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, many-to-many, django-views

I've got these two guys in models.py:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    movies = models.ManyToManyField(Movie)

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    release_year = models.IntegerField('release year', default=0000)
    plot = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

and this in views.py

```
class TagCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Tag
    success_url = '/movies/ratings/'
    fields = ["name"]
```

Im trying to set the "movies" field in the Tag class with the value of the current movie I'm "taggin" 
The URL is:

```
url(r'^(?P<movie_id>\d+)/tag/$', TagCreate.as_view(), name='tag'),
```

Thanxs in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this as a hidden field on the form. The data is in the URL, you can take it from there. The place to do this is in `form_valid`.

```
def form_valid(self):
    result = super(TagCreate, self).form_valid()
    movie = Movie.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['movie_id'])
    self.object.movies.add(movie)
    return result
```